# Changing header style not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm trying to change the appearance of my h1. I've done a part of the code but I noticed that it doesn't work in Chrome. Anyone know why? And if you have a suggestion how to better write the code below:

Link: http://codepen.io/Winterfox/pen/KzRbpZ

```
window.onload = function() {

var ownHeading = document.getElementById("heading");
var newHeading = document.getElementById("newheading");

ownHeading.addEventListener("input", buildLayout);

function buildLayout() {
   newHeading.innerHTML = ownHeading.value;
};

/*---------------------------------------------------------*/

var changeStyleBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("changestyle-btn");
 var changeStyleUl = document.getElementById('change-h-font');

for (var i = 0; i < changeStyleBtn.length; i++) {
    changeStyleBtn[i].addEventListener('click', changeStyle, false);
}

function changeStyle() {

  changeStyleUl.style.display = "block";
};

/*-------------------------------------------------------*/

var changeStyleLi = changeStyleUl.getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0; i < changeStyleLi.length; i++) {
    changeStyleLi[i].addEventListener('click', changeFont, false);
 }

function changeFont() {
  // here it stops working in chrome (can't click on lis)
  alert("clic");
  console.log(this);
};

};
```

Comment: Could you mark the line of code with comments, where you face the problem? What is it that "doesn't work" ? what do you want to achieve? I have seen the codepen link It works for me.

Comment: It's the last lines, where you try to click on the lis that are displayed in the codepen.

Comment: it does work? I am on a chrome browser. Clicking the li is showing me the alert. Chrome: Version 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit)

Comment: It's probably a chrome bug.  Delete all your css then it works

Answer (score 1):

Issue appears to be with the `ul` element being embedded `#changestyle-btn` `div`

```
<div class="changestyle-btn">+
    <ul class="changestyle" id="change-h-font">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Once I move the element out of the `div` it works fine in Chrome.

```
<div class="changestyle-btn">+</div>
<ul class="changestyle" id="change-h-font">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

This is most likely because you have already bound a click event to the `#changestyle-btn` `div` so when you attempt to click the `li` element it is only firing the first event.

Comment: @zjk It is most likely just the way the Firefox interprets the JS, Chrome is most probably a little stricter when it comes to overlapping elements with `click` binds